# Why Buttons are floating on top of RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_buy_more"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Buy More"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/recycler_view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_checkout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Checkout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_buy_more" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Logout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_checkout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the result:

[image]

The RecyclerView fills the entire screen height. And the Buttons are not located below the RecyclerView, but floating on top of it. This is not what I want.

What I want is the Buttons to be located fixed below the RecyclerView. How to fix this?

Comment: Default button style includes `elevation` which causes them to be drawn on top, even if they are under `RecyclerView` in view hierarchy.

Comment: @tynn Ah sorry. Fixed that. Just updated the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have set the `layout_height` of the `recyclerView` to `match_parent` which will take the full height of the app. to fix this you will need to set its constraint to the logout button and `layout_height` to `0dp` .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_logout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_buy_more"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Buy More"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_checkout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Checkout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_buy_more" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Logout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_checkout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make some changes to set buttons correctly

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="warp_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/btn_buy_more"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:text="Buy More"
     />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_checkout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Checkout"
       />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:text="Logout"
     />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `match_parent` inside a **ConstraintLayout**. `match_parent` is logically not related with **ConstraintLayout**. Add your constraints like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_logout"
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RecyclerView` is matching the parent and even aligns to the bottom of the parent.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Instead you should constrain it to the buttons and match the constraints (a hight or width of `0dp`).

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_logout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
```